# how to use RelatedField in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have problem with Django restframe work i have 2 table that one of them is a foreign key to another i have used RelatedField in serializer but i get an error:'Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, 
can someone help me in this case
my code is as below:

```
class DocTable(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    document_no = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    document_title = models.TextField(null=True, default='', blank=True)

class PlanTable(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(DocTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='doctable')
    work_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    description_work = models.TextField(null=True, default='', blank=True)
```

```
serializers.py

class DocTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doctable = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = DocTable
        fields = ['pk', 'project', 'document_no', 'doctable']
        read_only_fields = ['pk']


class PlanTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlanTable
        fields = ['pk', 'document', 'work_type', 'description_work']
        read_only_fields = ['pk']
```

```
views.py
class  DocTableListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class =  DocTableSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PlanTable.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return PlanTable.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide queryset in `RelatedField` like this.

```
class DocTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doctable = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, queryset=DocTable.objects.all())
```

Or if you only want to use this related field for retrieving data, you can mark it as read only

```
doctable = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Comment: i have add queryset=DocTable.objects.all() but get an error DocTable' object has no attribute 'doctable'.